# get posts whether meta_key exists or not

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I am trying to get custom posts using **$wpdb->get_results()** as follows:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_content, p.post_title, p.post_excerpt, 
pm1.meta_value as meal_date, 
(case when pm2.meta_key is null then '' else pm2.meta_value end) as meal_plan,
t.name as meal_type 
FROM wp_posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS r ON (p.ID = r.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS x ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS t ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta As pm1 ON (p.ID = pm1.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta As pm2 ON (p.ID = pm2.post_id)
WHERE p.post_type IN ('knl_meals') 
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND x.taxonomy = 'knl_meal_types'

AND pm1.meta_key = '_knl_meal_date'
AND pm2.meta_key = '_knl_meal_regular'

AND STR_TO_DATE(pm1.meta_value, '%M %d, %Y') BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(pm1.meta_value, '%M %d, %Y') ASC,t.term_id ASC, p.menu_order ASC, p.post_date DESC;
```

Basically, I want meal_plan to be **meta_value** for **meta_key = _knl_meal_regular** if it exists, otherwise empty string/bool false etc type value for the post but the post should be included in the results. Right now, it is excluding the posts if meta_key does not exist for a post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Hobo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39303269/356188) which gave me the clue for moving pm2 condition to the join statement

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_content, p.post_title, p.post_excerpt, pm1.meta_value as meal_date, pm2.meta_value as meal_plan, t.name as meal_type
FROM wp_posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS r ON (p.ID = r.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS x ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS t ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta As pm1 ON (p.ID = pm1.post_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta As pm2 ON (p.ID = pm2.post_id and pm2.meta_key='_knl_meal_regular')
WHERE p.post_type IN ('knl_meals') 
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND x.taxonomy = 'knl_meal_types'

AND pm1.meta_key = '_knl_meal_date'
AND STR_TO_DATE(pm1.meta_value, '%M %d, %Y') BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(pm1.meta_value, '%M %d, %Y') ASC,t.term_id ASC, p.menu_order ASC, p.post_date DESC;
```